# Is there a way to acess usb camera feed rather than internal cameras on video capture?

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, mediadevices

I currently have a form with a file input that accepts video captures. By default it opens the devices internal camera, in this case, a tablets front camera. The problem is that I have a endoscopic industrial camera connected to the tablets usb port, the camera works fine on third party apps, but i would like to use it for the video capture input, meaning that i want to use the endoscopic camera to record the video rather than the internal ones. Is this possible with HTML5 capture and javasrcipt?

I already tried all variations of getUserMedia() but they all result in accessing the internal cameras only.

Here is the code that im using for testing.

```
<video  width="1280" height="720"></video>
<p onclick="capture()">capture</p>
<script>
    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            deviceId: '3caac644b0fa5838e6e720169a3b3c52e18f449625455e65924eb112a22f8bd9',
            width: { ideal: 1280 },
            height: { ideal: 720 }
        }
    };

    function capture(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((mediaStream) => {
            const video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject = mediaStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            video.play();
            };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // always check for errors at the end.
            console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? [How to use the external web cam on browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73678623/how-to-use-the-external-web-cam-on-browsers) I would recommend trying the answer and GrafiCode's comment on the question to see if that helps you do what you need.

Comment: @JacobK I attempted what the comment said but all I get is the following error. "NotReadableError: Could not start video source"